# $T:L^2[0,1]\to L^1[0,1]$ surjective

Tags: functional-analysis

Is it possible to find a lineal, continuous and surjective operator from $T:L^2[0,1]\to L^1[0,1]$?

I think it is not possible but I don't know how to prove it. Can somebody help me? Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if you could find a mapping by writing out a Hamel basis for each and relating them by way of $T$. If you force continuity on $T$ so that you can take limits, it might work?

Comment: I know that $(e^{int})_n$ is a hilbertian basis of $L^2[0,1]$, but I don't know how to write a Hamel basis.

Comment: Hamel bases are given by the axiom of choice, so you can't really write one down. They are uncountable by nature.

Comment: See the first (or second) answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165048/does-there-exist-any-surjective-continuous-linear-map-tl2-to-l1).